# checkbox in toc is not working

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, table-of-contents

I have toc with dynamic and feature layers.its displaying properlybut when I checked on and off the checkbox nothing is changing on layer.

below is code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>Create a Map</title>  
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">  
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/esri/css/esri.css">  
    <!--<link href="agsjs/dijit/css/TOC.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/tags/agsjs/latest/build/agsjs/css/agsjs.css" />  
    <style>  
        html, body, #mapDiv {  
            padding: 0;  
            margin: 0;  
            height: 100%;  
            width: 100%;  
            overflow: hidden;  
        }  

        #tocDiv {  
            z-index: 50;  
            position: absolute;  
            top: 0%;  
            left: 0%;  
            width: 300px;  
            height: auto;  
            background-color: White;  
        }  

        #divDialogProcess {  
            z-index: 50;  
            position: absolute;  
            right: 0%;  
            top: 0%;  
            background-color: White;  
        }  
    </style>  
    <script>  
        var dojoConfig = {  
            packages: [{  
                name: "agsjs",  
                "location": '/2.10/build/agsjs' // for xdomain load  
            }]  
        };  
    </script>  


    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/"></script>  
    <script>  
        var map, tiled, pointFeatureLayer, operationalLayer;  
        require(["dojo/_base/connect",
        "esri/map", "esri/config",  
                 "esri/geometry/Extent",  
                 "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",  
                 "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",  
                 "esri/renderers/ClassBreaksRenderer",  
                 "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",  
                 "esri/tasks/GeometryService",  
                 "dojo/dom",  
                 "dojo/dom-geometry",  
                 "dojo/fx",  
                 "dojo/on",  
                 "dojo/parser",  
                 "dojo/_base/Color",  
                 "agsjs/dijit/TOC",
                 "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", 
                 "dijit/layout/ContentPane",                     
                 "dojo/domReady!"], function (connect,Map, esriConfig, Extent, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, FeatureLayer, ClassBreaksRenderer, SimpleFillSymbol, GeometryService, dom, domGeom, coreFx, on, parser, Color, TOC  
        ) {  

                map = new Map("mapDiv", {
                 center: [77.2, 14],
                 zoom: 7,
                 basemap: "topo",
                 slider: false

             });

                     operationalLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://.../arcgisserver/rest/services/CRD/CRD1/MapServer", { id: "Operational", opacity: 0.5 });  

                     pointFeatureLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://.../arcgisserver/rest/services/CRD/CRD2/FeatureServer/0", { id: "Points"

                     });  

                     map.addLayers([operationalLayer, pointFeatureLayer]);  

                     // Add Table of Contents Start  
                   map.on('layers-add-result', function (evt) {  
                         try {  

                             var toc = new TOC({  
                                 map: map,  
                                 layerInfos: [{  
                                     layer: pointFeatureLayer,  
                                     title: "My Feature"  
                                 }, {  
                                     layer: operationalLayer,  
                                     title: "Dynamic Map"  
                                 }]  
                             }, "tocDiv");  
                             toc.startup();  

                             toc.on("load", function () {  
                                 console.log("TOC loaded");  
                             });   
                         }  
                         catch (e) { console.error(e.message); }  


                     });   
                 }  
        );  
    </script>  
</head>  
<body class="soria">  
    <div id="mapDiv">  
        <div id="tocDiv"></div>  
    </div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

can any tell whats wrong in above code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a `MapServer` that has a `Single Fused Map Cache: true` which mean that your `MapServer` is a Cached service (designed to work with `esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer`, in other terms, a service as basemap) .

So You can't hide each layers of this service apart , you can only hide the entire service  layers at ones.

if you want your to fixe the probleme you have to publich another `.../services/CRD/CRD1/MapServer` but without cache .( non cached serivce )